# How to hide the columns of one list when you have two lists on the page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, classic-experience

How can I hide the columns of a specific list. When I have 2 lists on my page.

this code below hides the columns of all the lists.

```
  #WebPartCaptionWPQ9 tr.ms-viewheadertr
  {
     display: none
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to hide the column "headers" of list web part from classic page? Or do you want to remove the complete column (header + data) from list web part?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can try changing the **Edit Current View** of list in which you want to hide the columns.
Afterwards you just need to unselect the columns you want to hide. You can follow the Screenshots.[image]

Comment: Are you trying to hide the column "headers" of list web part from classic page? YES :)